# What's the Dirichlet inverse of $f(n) = 2^{n - 1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I computed the first few values which were $1, -2, -4, -4, -16, -16, -64, -104, -240$. Is there a simple expression for this?

Comment: OEIS says no ${}$

Comment: How did you compute the -for instance - first four or five values? I couldn't decode the wikipedia-entry... *(perhaps you could include such examples in your question giving redundance for the casual reader)*